# show specific message when no record come in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my Oracle query which gets records on the basis of date where differences of dates should be one month:

```
  select *
   from pbxhbl.HBL_TRANSACTIONS  
  where dat_creation between '10-apr-2013' and '10-jun-2013' 
    and MONTHS_BETWEEN('10-jun-2013','10-apr-2013') = 1
```

My question is, when difference is more than one I want to show a message:

> 'date duration should be one month'

Comment: I think this kind of check must be in application level not in the dbms level

Comment: It wont show them if you have the `MONTHS_BETWEEN('10-jun-2013','10-apr-2013') = 1` in the where clause, unless you want it as a separate query

Comment: Which dates should not exceed one month? All `dat_creation`'s (i.e. `min(dat_creation)` and `max(dat_creation)`)? Or do you have another date?

Comment: For me it seems like you could use a function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> MONTHS_BETWEEN('10-jun-2013','10-apr-2013')

Firstly, `'10-jun-2013'` is not a **DATE**, it is a **STRING**. Oracle will do an implicit data type conversion. Please avoid this, and always use **TO_DATE** to explicitly convert a string into date.

Secondly, months between the two dates that you have posted will **never be 1**, it **will always be 2**.

```
SQL> SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date('10-jun-2013','dd-mon-yyyy'),to_date('10-apr-2013','dd-mon-yyyy')) dt
  2  FROM dual;

        DT
----------
         2

SQL>
```

So, ideally your query will always **return no rows**.

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM dual
  3  WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date('10-jun-2013','dd-mon-yyyy'),to_date('10-apr-2013','dd-mon-yyyy')) =1;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Coming back to your question,

You could use a **CASE** expression.

However, if you are filtering out rows, then you would not have anything to display. So, remove the filter, such that whenever the value of `MONTHS_BETWEEN` is more than 1, you could return the message.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT to_date('01-03-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') dt1, to_date('01-04-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') dt2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT to_date('01-03-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') dt1, to_date('10-04-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') dt2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT to_date('01-03-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') dt1, to_date('01-05-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') dt2 FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT DT1,
  7    DT2,
  8    CASE
  9      WHEN months_between(dt2, dt1) >1
 10      THEN 'date duration should be one month'
 11      ELSE 'OK'
 12    END MESSAGE
 13  FROM DATA;

DT1       DT2       MESSAGE
--------- --------- ---------------------------------
01-MAR-15 01-APR-15 OK
01-MAR-15 10-APR-15 date duration should be one month
01-MAR-15 01-MAY-15 date duration should be one month

SQL>
```

Comment: Your answer would produce a message for every matched row. I suppose the OP is asking for a single message (on statement level, not on each row).

Answer (score 0):

What you need should be done inside a function.

Create a function that takes two parameters as input `(date, date)` and as an output it returns a record of table type.

Inside a function, before passing your query to output insert a conditional control structure like `CASE` or `IF` to check whether or not given dates match your criteria. If yes, simply pass the query to the result, and if no (assuming you would like someone to see it in application) return a query that is built just as the record you would normally return and include your message in one of columns while the rest should remain `NULL`.

For the above I assumed that raising an error is not what you actually need.

Pseudocode:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_dates_for_hbl_transactions(date, date)
RETURNS record
AS $function$
BEGIN
IF ( MONTHS_BETWEEN( $1 - $2 ) > 1 )
THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT 'Date duration should be one month at max'::text, NULL::bigint, ...
ELSE
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM HBL_TRANSACTIONS WHERE dat_creation BETWEEN $1 AND $2
END IF;
END
$function$
```

**Important note**: The reason I wrote `'message'::text, NULL::bigint, ...` was to show that your select statement must match the returning set (in this case all the columns and their types from table `HBL_TRANSACTIONS`).

Also consider adding an additional check for date $2 to be larger than date $1 argument.

**Side note**: Consider returning rowtype to make it easier. I do not prefer that method as it is error prone in case of row type being changed. I'd rather have the function to fail and check manually for the cause than have it pass normally as usual with wrong value.